# Can I use ResourceDictionary and UserControl not in WPF app

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am going to create an add-in for a CAD application. Its API allows us to introduce ClassLibrary project, and to implement the UI we can use UserControl.

I've added UserControl and introduced plugin, it works great. But when I try to add Material design styles http://materialdesigninxaml.net/ and add Resources to the UserControl, I get the error on InitializeComponent() method called:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.'
>
> NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

The UserControl code:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Could you specify can I use ResourceDictionary and UserControl out of the WPF app?

Answer (score 2):

1.- Install MaterialDesignThemes nuget: Install-Package MaterialDesignThemes

2.- Edit AXML file

```
<UserControl ......

xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
TextElement.FontSize="13"
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}">


<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what worked for me was to install the nuget package on the entry point project for the wpf app.
If you don't put the resource dictionaries of MaterialDesign anywhere besides your user control (as you posted) it shouldn't affect other part of the application, it didn't for me at least